# WebDAV Server Engine for .NET questions

Tags: .net, webdav

1. How can I force a file to be opened in read-only mode in cases where a certain custom document status applies? For instance, a document can go through various stages: created, reviewed, approved. Once it's approved nobody can modify it.
2. How do I tell a client through the WebDAV Server Engine for .NET api that certain operations are not supported, for instance moving and copying files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to forbid copy and move operations in all cases, do it this way:

```
public override void CopyTo(IItemCollection folder, string destName, bool deep, MultistatusException multistatus)
{
    throw new DavException("Cannot copy resource", DavStatus.NOT_ALLOWED);
}

public override void MoveTo(IItemCollection folder, string destName, MultistatusException multistatus)
{
    throw new DavException("Cannot move resource", DavStatus.NOT_ALLOWED);
}
```

If you want to forbid copy/move/change a resource basing on some condition, I'll recommend you to use custom handlers:

```
public Service(ILogger logger, bool isApplication)
{
    ...
    MyCustomPutHandler handler = new MyCustomPutHandler();
    handler.OriginalHandler = engine.RegisterMethodHandler("PUT", handler);
}

internal class MyCustomPutHandler : IMethodHandler
{
    public IMethodHandler OriginalHandler { get; set; }

    public void ProcessRequest(DavContextBase context, IHierarchyItem item)
    {
        if(<check condition>)
        {
            throw new DavException("Cannot change resource", DavStatus.Conflict);
        }
        if (item is IFolder)
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            OriginalHandler.ProcessRequest(context, item);
        }
    }
     ......
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

> "How can I force a file to be opened in read-only mode..."

In case you are using Windows Explorer (Windows Shell/Miniredirector/WebFolders) and MS Office you can implement [IMsItem](http://doc3.webdavsystem.com/ITHit.WebDAV.Server.MicrosoftExtensions.IMsItem.html) that will return file attributes for the item. In your IMsItem.GetFileAttributes method implementation add the read-only flag:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns Windows file attributes (readonly, hidden etc.) for this file/folder.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Windows file attributes.</returns>
public FileAttributes GetFileAttributes()
{
    if (Name.StartsWith("."))
    {
        return fileSystemInfo.Attributes | FileAttributes.Hidden;
    }
    return fileSystemInfo.Attributes | FileAttributes.ReadOnly;
}
```

However this code does not actually protects your file from being overwritten by other users/applications. To protect a file from modifications you must check if user has enough permissions to modify the file in your [IFile.Write](http://doc3.webdavsystem.com/ITHit.WebDAV.Server.IContent.Write.html) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

> "How do I tell a client through the WebDAV Server Engine for .NET api
>   that certain operations are not supported, for instance moving and
>   copying files."

Hypothetically you can remove remove COPY and MOVE verbs from Allow and Public headers returned in response to OPTIONS request (see example below). You will need to call:

```
engine.RegisterMethodHandler("COPY", null);
engine.RegisterMethodHandler("MOVE", null);
```

However, according to my experience, Microsoft Miniredirector and Microsoft Office may become unusable after that. Microsoft Office may open files as read-only. If you need to support MS Office and Miniredirector I would suggest to keep all verbs in Allow and Public headers. Just throw DavException in CopyTo and MoveTo implementation as Taras suggested in his answer.

The example of options request:

```
OPTIONS http://ajaxbrowser.com/Userb7d072f HTTP/1.1
translate: f
User-Agent: Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.0.6002
Host: ajaxbrowser.com
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow: COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNLOCK
Content-Length: 0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/1.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: ACL, CANCELUPLOAD, CHECKIN, CHECKOUT, COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MKCALENDAR, MKCOL, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNCHECKOUT, UNLOCK, UPDATE, VERSION-CONTROL
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Overwrite, Destination, Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, Translate, Range, Timeout, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control
Access-Control-Max-Age: 2147483647
X-Engine: IT Hit WebDAV Server .Net v3.0.556.0 (Evaluation License)
DAV: 1, 2, 3
Public: COPY, DELETE, GET, HEAD, LOCK, MOVE, OPTIONS, POST, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, PUT, REPORT, UNLOCK
MS-Author-Via: DAV
Date: Fri, 23 Nov 2012 20:26:51 GMT
```